# AWS - Is there anything the API can't do ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

A mostly pointless question but I'm curious none the less and google gave me nothing (so hey lets let google index this one for next time)

Is there anything that explicitly cannot be done on an AWS account through the API alone?

eg. Is there something you MUST log in to the console, or even some other method perhaps ?
For arguments sake, if I were to go ahead and develop an exact copy of the web console, obviously utilising the API, is there anything my web console couldnt do?

Comment: Not as far as I know. The reverse applies, so there are API functions that aren't exposed in the AWS UI, but AFAIK the Console is using the API under the hood so it must be feature complete.

Comment: Just to add a comment the same as @LDJ but phrased slightly different:  both the AWS Console UI and the AWS API access the underlying services, which are mostly (all?) exposed as REST endpoints.  So it is possible that (for instance) an outdated API toolkit might not be able to do something that the console could do.  But the limitation is what is available from the endpoints

Comment: Of course! I had forgotten about the reverse applying @LDJ thanks, I now specifically remember my amazon trainer going through a few examples of things that could only be done in the cli (or using the api)
Which kind of implies what you are saying, though I just read a comment on another question here that there exists no proper API for billing, though this is not really part of the AWS "cloud" so much.

Comment: Your web console also couldn't use IAM users' passwords for logins -- it would need its own user authentication mechanism. *Q: Is there an authentication API to verify IAM user sign-ins?
No. There is no programmatic way to verify user sign-ins.* https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#login_anchor

Comment: interesting, I did not know that about IAM users.
Though you could just use API KEYS/SECRETS, store them in a table with a user/pass simble combo to access the keys on auth and then inject them in to the API that is running the web console, essentially seeming like they logged in with the API keys but a more human readable user/pass combo

Answer (score 4):

There are features that are available only in the console.  For example, the recently released ability to see the last time a particular IAM user or role was actually used is available only in the console.  And scheduled Lambda functions originally appeared as a console-only feature but is now available via the CloudWatch Events API.

It's a pretty rare thing.  For the most part, the console is built on the API's but it does happen.

And there are many examples of capabilities in the SDK's that are not available in the console.